# DJI spark pattern flight

Tags: dji-sdk

Hello ~ I am a Korean student who is studying how to make 'DJI SPARK' app using Android Studio.﻿ The app I want to create is to allow the drones to shoot a stationary object with a certain pattern(For example, a pattern that rotates about an object constantly). However, I could not find information on the homepage.​

I uploaded the DJI Sample Code to Android Studio, entered an app key on the Android Manifest.xml file. Then I think I need to put coding into MissionManager, but I do not know how to make the code to implement the pattern. I need help from several developers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can help but most of what you ask sounds specific to your project and I don't want to give you the answer.

I will gladly point you into the correct directions and help you locale the specific areas of the documentation in order to compete for project.

Comment: Recommend move to chat.

Comment: thank you for feedback~ I code 'HotpointMissionOperator' and '' WaypointMissionOperator '' for the 'Missionoperator' part, and I was able to implement the pattern I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use DJI's APIs under Mission Classes - specifically the [HotpointMissionOperator](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIHotpointMissionOperator.html) and [WaypointMissionOperator](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointMissionOperator.html.)

The Hotpoint Mission will allow your drone to fly circles around a specified point. If you want to fly a different pattern other than a circle then you can plot out a series of points with Waypoint Missions in whichever pattern you designate.

Comment: thank you for feedback~ Thanks to your feedback, I was able to solve my questions and implement the pattern I wanted.